# C++ concat const char with value from #define

Tags: c++, string, char

i have defined a value using

```
#define username "admin"
```

then i want to use the username in a char statement into sql as

```
const char *pSQL[1];
pSQL[1] = "update websrv_config set admin_id='" + username + "'";
```

but it seems that there is an error

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [36]’ and ‘const char [6]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

how can i overcome it?

Comment: Just get rid of the `+` operators: `pSQL[1] = "update websrv_config set admin_id='" username "'";`

Comment: C and C++ arrays use 0-based indexing.  Declaring an array of length 1 and then accessing the element at index 1 is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pSQL[0] = "update websrv_config set admin_id='"  username  "'";
```

In c++ array index starts with 0 so when you have decleared an array of length 1. The only index it can have is 0. Further, '+' is not used for concatenation in c++.

Answer (score 2):

That's a C-string, not a `std::string` (and what you'd do in C, not C++), but if you **must**, you can do this:

```
pSQL[0] = "update websrv_config set admin_id='"  username  "'";
```

C-strings can't be concatenated with `+` because they're string literals.

I'd use a `std::string` if I were you:

```
std::string sql = "update websrv_config set admin_id='";
sql += username;
sql += "'";
```

and you can get the contents in `const char*` format (if needed) with

```
sql.c_str();
```

Also, note that since `username` is a macro, you can't change it at runtime.

Also, if you get rid of the macro, think about some evil mastermind providing a username like:

```
"johnny'; DROP TABLE websrv_config;"
```

Comment: The OP is dealing with *string literals*, and not pointers to arrays.

Comment: @JesseGood underneath, a string literal is still a `const char*` or whatever. But, yeah, that's what I meant. Edited ;)

Comment: Actually, that is incorrect, look at the error message in the question, the string literal has type `const char [36]`. String literals are always *arrays*.

Comment: @JesseGood ergo the "whatever" :D